# Java RestService writing and reading data from log files

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, web

I have a  Java Rest Servcie which Consumes data Posted by  java Rest Client.
When Client Post the Data into my Rest Service,i am updating data in some tables.
If my database is down.I want to store Client posted  data into some log files.

when client post new data again,that time we need to read the log file data again and update in some tables.

Could any one  i want to know how to write and read data from log files in java Rest service application.where log files get stored?

Comment: You write to log files using logging framework such as the BackLog, or write your own i guess. Since log file is just a normal file, you read it same way as any other file. Files get stored where you specify them in configuration of logging framework.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution would be to put the messages in some temporary reliable storage such as JMS, for example. If you want to keep it simple, then change the code to write the data to the files (not to the database) and write another component to read the data from the files and save into the database. This component needs to delete the read data only if the DB transaction was completed successfully.

Comment: Once client post the data into my Rest service .we have to send Success Acknowledgement Back to the client when we update client posted data in Data  base or log files (if database is down)